# c# - How to get a specific item from a list of items in model and display the properties of the selected item on button click?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I pass a list of a specific object type from the controller to a partial view as model for the view. It is displayed in a table with each row containing minimum information about each object from the model. Each row has a button, which when clicked, launches a bootstrap modal and displays full details of the object. When the button is clicked, I want to be able to get the corresponding item from the list of items in the model and display all it's properties.

Assume the following are the types in my model.

```
List<T> ObjectList - Model
T Object - Individual object
```

How can I pass the ID of the object on button click and retrieve the item from the list of items in the model without querying the database again for the details of the object?

Comment: The web is stateless. If you have not included all the properties of each object in the view, then you need to call the database again (unless you have cached the collection somewhere)

Comment: All the properties of each object is present in the list of objects in the model. How can I access one from them and display?

Comment: Your model is on the server, not the client (unless you have included all the properties of all objects in the view  - e.g. by serializing to a javascript array, or using `data-*` attributes or hidden inputs etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom attribute, like put attribute `itemid` and pass button object to method as below

```
<button type="button" itemid = '@model.id' onclick="showModal(this)">Show Details!</button>
```

and in js, while writing definitation for that method, get id by using `attr()` of JQuery.

```
function showModal(obj) {
    var id = $(obj).attr('itemid');
    // your code here
}
```

I passed entire object to the method, you can pass just id, but passing object will help you when you pass other details too.

Comment: How can I get the element from the list using this Id?

Comment: How can I do that? I have the object ID in a javascript variable. How can I use this to get an element from the list?

Comment: You can access that object in javascript too by using `@` delimeter. and fire a linq there to get current object.

Comment: @Imad, I think you have misunderstood what OP is asking. The question is about getting the other properties of an object from the collection when clicking on a button without calling the server (linq is server side code)

Comment: @StephenMuecke He wants to pass id of current object to retrieve details `How can I pass the ID of the object on button click and retrieve the item from the list of items in the model without querying the database again` but yes, you are right, my answer is half correct.

Comment: So it is impossible to do this without querying the database again?

Comment: @NimishDavidMathew, obviously you can do it. You query all the data, including details and show whatever you want and keep hidden data in hidden fields. In detail modal, show data from hidden fieldds.

Comment: Yes. I did it. I used @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model) to store the model into a javascript variable. Then looped through the variable to find a match for the Id. Thanks for the help!